# Automating Bluetooth Device Pairing in C# Application for Windows PC

Tags: c#, .net, windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing a software application in C# with the aim of connecting devices to my Windows PC. Currently, I have successfully implemented the pairing process in my code. However, each time I want a device to pair, I have to manually run my code. What I aim for is to initiate the pairing process through my software, and afterward, I want the paired devices to appear in the Bluetooth settings of my PC automatically.

In essence, I want my software to handle the pairing process seamlessly without requiring manual intervention, and for the paired devices to be readily visible within the PC's Bluetooth settings after the pairing is completed.

Can someone help me please.

For the moment I only have :

```
await DeviceInformation
.FindAllAsync(BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromPairingState(true));
```

and

```
await DeviceInformation
.FindAllAsync(BluetoothDevice.GetDeviceSelectorFromConnectionStatus(BluetoothConnectionStatus.Connected));
```

That give  me the list of the Bluetooth devices that are currently connected and paired.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What looks like a nice convenience feature to you may look like a nice Trojan feature to others. It makes sense that minimal security features always require a user action. 
If security is not an issue, you should look at the "No Input No Output" IO capabilities for pairing.

Comment: Please do some basic research on why Bluetooth security is what it is.